# An Example of Unit Test for Time Triggered Azure function

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-functions

I am a newbie in Azure Functions.
I have implemented a time triggered azure function and wish to write unit test cases for it.
I am using specflow and nunit for writing my testcases.
However, I am unable to find a proper example of how to stub time trigger function.
Can someone point me to the correct example?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it a unit test anymore but you can trigger non-HTTP functions by calling the following admin endpoint of the function app:

`POST <ROOT_URL>/admin/functions/<FUNCTION_NAME>`

Note that you need to specify the system key in the `x-functions-key` header when making a request to a deployed function app.

More info in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http).

**Alternative**

What I usually try to do is put as much of the business logic in a seperate class which is easily testable and call this class from a function.

Personally, I don't think you should test if the trigger works, that's the responsibility of the Azure Functions Runtime. Fine to test this in a larger scoped integration test but not as a fast and frequently executed unit test.

Comment: I can hit this endpoint when running it locally, but not when writing an integration test with WireMock. Any tips on getting that working? All I get is 404 that way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the business logic out of the function itself, and instead have the function call libraries.
2. Add tests for those libraries.

You don't need to do anything that's specific to azure functions in order to test your code.

If you are attempting to do integration testing, then follow Marc's advice.